# How does ustream work?

Tags: c++, unicode, icu

I want to enable my program to output Greek letters. I've got ICU installed and linked up, but I can't figure out how to print my Unicode string to standard output. Here's some simple code:

```
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustring.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    UnicodeString mystr("αβγ");
    std::cout << mystr << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling with: `g++ ./ctest.cpp -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lpthread -lm` yields the following error:

> ctest.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `icu_46::operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&, icu_46::UnicodeString const&)'
>       collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

ICU's documentation is difficult for a noob like me, and it's especially sparse for `ustream.h`, which I think is the key to what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated (especially if anyone would like to write a more user-friendly guide to ICU!).

Comment: any suggestions ? i.e., where did you look, where would you have expected a pointer?  Actually there's no reference to ustream / ustdio  in the user's guide. Filed a ticket here: http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/9773   -- srl,(ICU)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-licuio` flag, since io operations for ICU are in this library.
http://userguide.icu-project.org/howtouseicu

```
forever@pterois:~/My_pro1/cpp_pro$ g++ -o new new.cpp -licui18n
-licuuc -licudata -licuio -lpthread -lm
forever@pterois:~/My_pro1/cpp_pro$ ./new 
αβγ
```

Comment: Ah link errors... I noted that in Douglas Gregor's proposal for Modules in C++ there is a `link` flag that will allow a module to specify which libraries to link, maybe one day forgetting a flag will be a woe of the past.

Comment: @MatthieuM. maybe- you could also use "pkg-config --cflags --libs icu-io".